# How can I Import and export data using bcp command?

Tags: sql-server-2008, bcp

I am Trying to import and export data using bcp tool but it was giving errors which are:-

```
  SQLState = 08001, NativeError = -1
Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0]SQL Server Network Interfaces:
 Error Locating Server/Instance Specified [xFFFFFFFF].
SQLState = 08001, NativeError = -1
Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0]A network-related or instance-
specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Serve
r is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL S
erver is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Se
rver Books Online.
SQLState = S1T00, NativeError = 0
Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0]Login timeout expired
```

**I am currently using SQL server 2008 r2 version.**

Command Which are I am using:-

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn>bcp Alldbtypes.dbo.Misc_dty
    pes out C:\Workarea\Data\EmployeeData.dat -S 192.168.1.117\SqlSrv2008 -T
```

Please suggest me how can I use bcp command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to user the bpc, it is important to know the schema of your database.

I believe the Export will look something like this:

```
bcp "Select Column1, Column2 FROM Database.Schema.Table" queryout
C:\bcp_outputQuery.txt -SYourServerName -T -c
```

OR something like this:

```
bcp DatabaseName.Schema.TableName out C:\Data\tableout.txt -c –T
```

For the import it would look something like this:

```
bcp Database.Schema.Table in
C:\bcp_outputQuery.txt -SYourServername -T -c
```