# Create a query that generates an insert statement in SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables that I've been working with in our test environment that I need to copy into my SQL Express database so I can continue work on my interface. I would like to use the data that I already have populated in the test environment tables since I don't necessarily want to use production data. I already have the tables created on my local database, all I need to do is insert the data that I already have.

I'm wondering if it's possible to generate an insert query that would contain all of the data that is already in the test environment - something that I can just execute as a query on my local machine.

Is this possible? I can't necessarily work with live production data quite yet, as my interface will be manipulating it.

Comment: Why don't you use the data export tool from the test environment and insert the data?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I Import and export data using bcp command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38183470/how-can-i-import-and-export-data-using-bcp-command)

Comment: maybe something like this `insert into DB_EXPRESS.dbo.table1 (fields...)  select fields from table1`

Comment: Unclear.   What is the form of the data in your test environment?   Does it need to be transformed while copying it to your database?

Comment: Do you have any references/foreign keys to worry about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
1.  Connect to your TEST server on SQL Server management studio.
2.  Expand the Databases node.
3.  Right-click your Test Database > Tasks > Generate Scripts:
4.  The Introduction page opens. Select Next to open the Chose Objects page. You can select the entire database or specific objects in the database. Select  Script specific database objects (select tables table)
5.  Select Next to open the Set Scripting Options page. Here you can configure where to save the script and some additional advanced options.
a. Select Save to new query window.
b. Select Advanced and make sure these options are set:

    Types of data to script set to Data only.
```

Step 5.b
[image: Step 5.b]

Comment: The scripting features in SSMS are extraordinarily useful in these kinds of circumstances. And seem to be an under-utilized tool set. This does exactly what the OP is looking for; generates `INSERT` statements that become portable across machines.

Comment: Worked great. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use the SQL Server Import and Export Wizard instead: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/import-export-data/start-the-sql-server-import-and-export-wizard?view=sql-server-2017